# Swift Output Weekdays as Strings

Tags: swift

I want to use an enum to convert integers to the String name of Weekdays. I have come up with the following

```
// Enum to output days
enum EnumDays : Int
{
    case MONDAY = 0
    case TUESDAY
    case WEDNESDAY
    case THURSDAY
    case FRIDAY
    case SATURDAY
    case SUNDAY
}

var weekDay = EnumDays.init(rawValue: 0)
print("Day = \(String(describing: weekDay))")
```

But we output the type as in

> "Day = Optional(SubscriptInSwift.EnumDays.MONDAY)"

how can I produce an output as a String i.e.:

> "Day = Monday"

This question is a minimum example of a problem I have had for some time, and although this example is about weekdays I am looking for a solution of how to generally convert Integers to String.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Calendar class already provides an API for getting weekday names (among others).

Comment: Ok, but this is rather for the general case of converting an integer to a String, this is a specific implementation of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to *unwrap weekDay*

```
print("Day = \(String(describing: weekDay!))")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`CustomStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible)

```
enum EnumDays: Int, CustomStringConvertible
{
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .MONDAY:
            return "Monday"
        case .TUESDAY:
            return "Tuesday"
        case .WEDNESDAY:
            return "Wednesday"
        case .THURSDAY:
            return "Thursday"
        case .FRIDAY:
            return "Friday"
        case .SATURDAY:
            return "Saturday"
        case .SUNDAY:
            return "Sunday"
        }
    }
    case MONDAY,TUESDAY,WEDNESDAY,THURSDAY,FRIDAY,SATURDAY,SUNDAY
}
```

And use if let to unwrap the enum object

```
if let weekDay = EnumDays.init(rawValue: 0) {
    print("Day = \(weekDay)")
}
```

---

You can get the week days from the `Calendar.current.weekdaySymbols`

```
print(Calendar.current.weekdaySymbols)//["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
print(Calendar.current.shortWeekdaySymbols)//["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative pattern that I use that allows for localisation. I'll use your example of a calendar. Using an explicit value for each allows you to use phrases with spaces or other punctuation, and then means you can easily use localisation if other languages are required. You pay for elegance with extra code - you can decide if this is worthwhile.

```
enum DaysOfWeek : Int
{
  case MONDAY = 0
  case TUESDAY
  case WEDNESDAY
  case THURSDAY
  case FRIDAY
  case SATURDAY
  case SUNDAY

  var asString : String
  {
    var resource = ""
    switch self
    {
      case .MONDAY: resource =  "Monday"
      case .TUESDAY : resource =  "Tuesday"
      case .WEDNESDAY:  resource =  "Wednesday"
      ...
    }

    // Use Internationalization, as appropriate.
    return NSLocalizedString(resource, comment: resource)
  }

}
```

Comment: Of course in this specific case, there's no need to manually localize weekday names. Get them from Calendar. But in general, this is a nice approach.